# Font Awesome 5: some unicode won't display in html select

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-5

I have a html select with 2 items, each one should show a FA icon, but only one of them works.
Both icons only have the "sold" version available FA5 free.
Changing the font family to "Font Awesome 5 Free", did not help and then none of icons displayed.

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <style>
    select {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    }
  </style>
  <select style='font-weight: 900;'>
    <option>&#xf19d; Broke</option>
    <option>&#xf009; Working</option>
  </select>

  <br/><br/> Code valid as this shows <i class='fas'>&#xf19d;</i><br/><br/> But displayed icons have the solid style as free and the other styles are pro only<br /> https://fontawesome.com/icons/graduation-cap?style=solid f19d<br /> https://fontawesome.com/icons/th-large?style=solid
  f009<br />


  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JS+SVG method to load your icons so the one used inside the content `<i class='fas'>&#xf19d;</i>` will get transformed into an SVG. The unicde inside the select aren't considered by this and will rely on the `font-family: 'FontAwesome'` which is the old version and the first icon you are trying to show exist only in the V5 (unlike the second one).

To fix your issue, you need to load the CSS version and correct the `font-family`

```css
select {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0-1/css/all.css">

<select style='font-weight: 900;'>
  <option>&#xf19d; Broke</option>
  <option>&#xf009; Working</option>
</select>

<br/><br/> Code valid as this shows <i class='fas'>&#xf19d;</i><br/><br/> But displayed icons have the solid style as free and the other styles are pro only<br /> https://fontawesome.com/icons/graduation-cap?style=solid f19d<br /> https://fontawesome.com/icons/th-large?style=solid
f009
<br />
```